# Implementing Jquery for ratings in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm trying to implement a 5-star rating system on my site using jQuery Star Rating plugin (http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Overview). I have never used jQuery or Javascript before, but I saw that I could use the following code `<input name="star1" type="radio" class="star"/>` to get the star button. But instead I just see a regular radio button which makes me think I didn't install the plugin properly.

Is there anything special I need to do to get this plugin working (ex: pointing to the path where I put the code?) Sorry for the total noob question...

By the way, the backend is working perfectly... it's just the jquery stuff that I am utterly confused about.

Answer (score 0):

If the radios don't look like stars, you're likely missing the CSS.

The `class="star"` does nothing unless a stylesheet has defined something for `.star`. Make sure the css is on your page with something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/jQuery.Rating.css" />
```